# Spotify v1 dark UI styles

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I am migrating an existing spotify app to API v1, which has a lot of implications.
Switching most of the backend code was easy, but now I'm working on the frontend. Our app has a dark style, so regarding to the style guide it should have a dark track list.
I am unable to find any help in switching a v1-app to a dark UI. Do you know anything that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Spotify lists should get you what you need.  Is there something special about your track list that prevents using them?

https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/list-list.html

Comment: They do work, but there is no way of using a spotify-supplied dark style as you are told in the design guidelines

Comment: Yes, I agree the ability to have a dark playlist does seem to be missing.  Poked around in list-base.css in the inspector and I don't see any options hiding in there for dark lists.  I guess when they say "You can choose between a dark version and a light version." they mean "as long as you choose light" :)

Comment: There are no specific CSS styles for light / dark anymore in the API 1.0. The design guidelines are out of date right now, and we will review them soon. However, I can't find anywhere where it says that you should use a dark track list if your app is dark. I would recommend you to use the default style.

Comment: Yes, you are right - you're not explicitly told. Still looks kinda bad to have a bright white playlist right in our black app.
Modifying the white playlist to durn turk doesn't look feasible to me.